# The word "was" to not use in writing, dont use the word was

Tags: verbs, writing

My english teacher told me to get rid of all "was"s in my essay and to replace them. I did it even though it seemed a bit difficult to re-write all my sentences. When writing essays is the word "was" bad? Or it's just him?
To be honest, some of the sentences did sound better without the words.
He gave us a list of words to refrain from like "was, is, are, were, be , been and being."

Comment: What was his reasoning?  Can you give some examples?

Comment: This is complete and utter nonsense. Get a new teacher. And get your money back from the old one.

Answer (score 4):

Momal,

It sounds like your English teacher is trying to teach you to avoid using what is called the "passive voice".  By removing all the "was"s in your essay, did you also find that you had to switch around the subject and the object?

Some authorities advise against using the passive voice when possible, because the alternative, the "active voice," sounds more direct.

Wikipedia's [entry on passive voice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_passive_voice) is actually pretty good, and contains lots of arguments for and against using the passive voice.

I am confident that with continued practice, your writing will flow ever more naturally and you will develop a sense of when you prefer to use the passive voice.

Cheers!